# Upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 - desktop environment

Tags: upgrade, desktop-environments

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and using the Budgie Desktop Environment, if I decide to upgrade to 19.04 will I lose the customisation I made of that desktop environment?

Comment: Nope. DE is just another package and settings are configuration. When you upgrade system, packages are updated and configuration is kept as it was before upgrading.

Comment: If you clean install using 'format' of the whole disk or include your /home partition then yes [lost].  If you something-else install where you don't select 'format' of for example any partitions; the installer will erase system directories which may remove some global configuration (but will be minimal to none), but your own desktop settings will be in your $HOME folder so these will remain untouched.  `do-release-upgrade` and like tools cannot skip releases, except from LTS to the next LTS release (it can be made to, but that's untested & not advisable).

Answer (score 1):

You can't upgrade from 18.04 (LTS) to 19.04 directly, you will have to upgrade to 18.10 first, then to 19.04. When 20.04 (LTS) comes out, you can upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 directly.

Apart from that, [Kulfy's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136524/upgrade-to-ubuntu-19-04-desktop-environment#comment1884121_1136524) on your question is correct, DE is just application(s) and you won't lose configuration on upgrade.

Comment: i upgraded from ubuntu 18.04 straight to ubuntu 19.04 using this guide : https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-ubuntu-19-04-directly-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but I have been working on this update for 3 days now. Many ins and outs. But you can update to 19.04, you have to install 18.10 first. After that installation is finished, you must open a terminal in root (or sudo) and run:

```
do-release-upgrade -c #this checks to see if the upgrade is available
```

then run:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Some forums will say to run ***do-release-upgrade -d***, but that is only for the developers.

If it is available it will install. Just make sure that you have the correct display manager driver installed for your favorite environment (desktop, flavor, distribution).

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue upgrading to 18.04 first for some reason the libsdl update was showing in the update manager but refusing to update, this held back upgrade to 18.04, fixed by doing the libsdl update though synaptic then everything worked fine... now on track for all upgrates through to disco dingo.

Comment: sorry I  evreywhere it says 18.04 it should say 18.10

Comment: How this answers the question?